# all images in List(Of Bitmap) seem the same [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, bitmap

I'm trying to achieve an undo/redo system for a paint program. Using `List(Of Bitmap)`.
Every time I do "mouse up" on PictureBox (when I stop drawing) I add the Picturebox image to the BitmapList... and at the same time I use a Listbox which adds every time as an item the `BitmapList.count` so I can select an item from bitmap list by index more easily. So when I click undo I just select the `BitmapList.Item(Listbox.index -1)` and draws on canvas the selected image from the list... but it seems that nothing has changed.

Here is what I tried:

At the very start:

```vb
Dim UndoRedoHistory As New List(Of Bitmap)

Drawing.Image = Bitmap
```

and then on Picturebox mouse up:

```vb
UndoRedoHistory.Add(Drawing.Image)
ListBox1.Items.Add(UndoRedoHistory.Count)
ListBox1.SelectedIndex = UndoRedoHistory.Count - 1
```

On Undo click:

```vb
If Not ListBox1.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex -= 1
    Try
        Dim i As Image = UndoRedoHistory.Item(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
        Drawing.Image = i

        Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(Drawing.Image, 0, 0)
        Drawing.Refresh()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End If
```

Comment: Without seeing code, we don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure but this is almost certainly the case of adding the same object to the list multiple times, rather than multiple objects once each. Consider this. Let's say that you are adding people to a list.

I present myself to you wearing a red shirt and you write my name down on the list. A while later, I present myself again but this time I'm wearing a green shirt, and you write my name down on the list again. Later still, I present myself again while wearing a blue shirt and you add my name to the list again. If you were to then read out the names on the list and have each person present themselves in turn, would you be surprised that I presented myself three times, each time wearing a blue shirt? Of course not. That's exactly what you would expect. I was the same person all three times you added me to the list so I'm the same person each time you get me from the list and each time you get me from the list you would expect me to be wearing the last shirt I put on, not the one I was wearing when you made that entry to the list.

VB.NET is an object-oriented language and programming objects are design to behave the same way real-world objects do. That means that, if you have a list and you add the same `Bitmap` object to it multiple times, you will get the same `Bitmap` object back from each item and that object will be in the state it was in the last time you added or possibly even a later state, if you changed the object after adding it. I could put on a yellow shirt after you added me to your list, after all.

In short, if you expect your list to contain multiple distinct `Bitmap` objects then you need to add multiple distinct `Bitmap` objects to it in the first place. The only place you're adding items is here:

```vb
UndoRedoHistory.Add(Drawing.Image)
```

If `Drawing.Image` refers to the same `Bitmap` object every time you execute that code then your list only contains that one object. You need to either assign a new object to `Drawing.Image` each time before executing that code or else create a copy of that one `Bitmap` each time and add the copy to the list instead of the original.

Comment: Yo mean to do UndoRedoHistory.Add(Bitmap.clone)

Comment: @JustaDeveloper, if that's what you need to do then that's what you do. Your question was why all your list items were the same and I answered that question. The best way to get the different items you need is a different question so needs to be asked separately, along with all the information relevant to that question.

Comment: Or to just say Bitmap= new Bitmap(Dimension,Dimension)